# the qlabel can not trigger the mouse release event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I have a parent QLabel, and create a child QLabel to show some text. When I click on the child QLabel, the mousePressEvent on parent QLabel is OK but the mouseReleaseEvent can not be trigger. 
The code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()
        self.label = QLabel('hello<br/> world', self)
        self.label.adjustSize()
        self.label.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: {};".format(QColor(255, 0, 0).name())
        )
        self.label.move(QPoint(50, 50))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent)
        print('press')

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        super(MyLabel, self).mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent)
        print('release')

class Window(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.label = MyLabel()
        self.label.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-width: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I find the reason is the text in the child QLabel. If I show the text as 'hello world' rather than 'hello<.br/> world', the mouse release signal is OK when I click on the 'hello world' QLabel. So, if I need to show 'hello <.br/> world', how to fixed this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of mousePressEvent the event is passed from parent to son, and the son will not be passed if the parent accepts it, but by default the parent ignores it for what the son consumes it, but unlike mouseReleaseEvent the son consumes the event so the parent will not be notified.

If you want to better understand the concepts of mouse events, read the following article:

- [Mouse event propagation](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/).

In this case there is another alternative that avoids disabling the widget as indicated by [@Romha Korev](http://Romha%20Korev) that is to activate the flag [Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum):

```py
self.label = QLabel('hello<br/> world', self)
self.label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
```

This will make the widget below the QLabel receive the mouse events as if the QLabel did not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why the parent QLabel can receive the mouse events if I use QLabel('hello world', self)? And do you know how to excluded the green framebox?

Comment: @QiangZhang use `self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: {}; border: 0".format(QColor(255, 0, 0).name()))`

Comment: Thank you very much. But why the parent QLabel can receive the mouse events if I use QLabel('hello world', self)?

Comment: @QiangZhang In the case that unenriched text is used as "hello world" QLabel handles that event, but if it is enriched as HTML there is an internal element (a widget) that absorbs that event (it is part of the private API), of Anyway, the flag that points to you works for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the mouse button above the *hello world* label, the `MyLabel` will broadcast the event to its children.

So the *hello world* label will be the final receiver. And once it will receive the press event, it will automatically the receiver for the release event.

If you want to process all the event in `MyLabel`, you just need to disable the label by adding `self.label.setDisabled(True)` in the constructor: the press event will be limited to `MyLabel` and it will also receive the release event.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why the parent QLabel can receive the mouse events if I use QLabel('hello world', self)?